# Remove return key (\n) from read file

Tags: python

I have a jumble game that imports a random word from a text file. However, I think it is importing the return key. Once the word is jumbled I print it to screen and the word is split on two different lines.

How can I ignore the return key? If there is not a simple way to do this please let me know, because I will just settle for a tuple until I further my knowledge.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to strip off the newline (the "return key" character) when reading in the words: `word = line.strip()`.

Comment: A tip to display a string `ss`` in an uninterpreted manner : use ``repr(ss)``, it will display the ``\n`` and ``\r`` if they are present in the string as visible as this, not interpretd to trigger a newline appearance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're selecting a line from your file, you certainly get something like:

```
myword\n
```

... or `\r` and Mac or even `\r\n` on Windows... The sequence represents a break line, and you can easily remove it with Python built-in function.

Indeed, to avoid that, you can apply the `.strip()` function on the string to remove the \n and any undesired spaces:

```
>>> 'myword\n'.strip()
myword
```